# Removing Widget from Home Screen when Uninstalled

Tags: android, widget

When my application is uninstalled, a widget that is contained in this packages stays on the HOME
screen and gives an error message "problem loading widget".

How do I remove the widget when my application is uninstalled?  Is there an
attribute in the manifest that I am missing?

I thought this thing should be handled by the OS, but guess it is not.

**EDITED**:  I am now catching the "PACKAGE_ REMOVED" intent, and checking the "EXTRA_REPLACING" to make sure it's not a reinstall, but I don't know the actual code to use to actually remove the widget.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible - can you ever remove anything off of the Home screen?  The Home screen is another app, and I don't think it advertises its content through a Provider or anything like that.

Comment: No idea about removing anything from the HOME screen.  I am just amazed that the OS doesn't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add or remove app widgets from the home screen. Only the user can do that.

Quoting @CommonsWare [#4532121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532121/removing-appwidgets-programmatically)