# How to remove widget when the app is uninstalled in Android?

Tags: android, widget, uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing Widget from Home Screen when Uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860901/removing-widget-from-home-screen-when-uninstalled)

In Android, I have created a widget for my application. When I uninstall the app, the widget shows "problem loading widget" error in home screen. I need a scenario where widget should be removed by the developer through code (and not by the drag and drop to the trash) when I uninstall the app. Is it possible? If so, what changes we need to do? Is there anything that can be set in the manifest so that it removes all references of the app once it is uninstalled?

Comment: Any news about this subject? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiya! 
When you delete the app widget host manager should broadcast one of the following intents...
ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED
ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED
ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED

To make use of this, in your appwidget provider class (or your custom extension of broadcast receiver) receive the broadcast (or use onDeleted() in the appwidgetprovider class) and delete from the application widget host manager the widget with the id of your widget....

Hope this helps...

Comment: Did you actually try this? The messages you list are NOT sent when the app is deleted. Specifically, onDeleted() in AppWidgetProvider is only called when the Widget is removed, not the entire app.

Comment: Hey Carl, yes I tried this.  Additionally, I used androids dev site as a reference for my comment.  I will try it again ssometime as it has been almost a year since I wrote this comment.  Will let you know.

Comment: None of these broadcasts are sent if the *app* is uninstalled. Specifically, [ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED is sent when a *widget* is deleted from the home screen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED).

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to get control when your app is uninstalled. I think Android 2.2 may do a better job of automatically getting rid of your app widget.

Comment: Is there no way to have my widgets deleted once my app is uninstalled? Shouldn't the OS handle that?

Comment: @Janusz: "Shouldn't the OS handle that?" -- yes, which is why I wrote "I think Android 2.2 may do a better job of automatically getting rid of your app widget."

Comment: No sadly it does not. There are improvements for widgets announced for 3.0 maybe we have to wait until then.