# Uninstalling app which created widgets leaves "Problem loading widget" placeholder where they used to be

Tags: android, widget, uninstallation

My app suffers from this and it turns out so does the  Wiktionary sample from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Wiktionary/index.html.
Install the app, create a widget, uninstall the app - observe text as stated where widget used to be. Tried on Android 2.3.4.

I understand Widgets can't be rendered unless all their resources are available to them - are they trying to be drawn after the uninstall, when those resources clearly are gone?

Whilst struggling with this I saw the AppWidgetProvider.onDeleted() explanation says it's called when the ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED broadcast is sent. On my app this is true when I manually drag a widget to the trashcan. Is it also supposed to fire when you leave the widget on the home screen but uninstall the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think it does.  see here [How to remove widget when the app is uninstalled in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387742/how-to-remove-widget-when-the-app-is-uninstalled-in-android) (edited - sorry cut/paste failure)