# Android app Widget update new version removes the existing widget

Tags: android, widget

I developed an APP + Home screen widget for Android. Now I updated the app (incremented the version code/name) but when i install, it doesn't automatically replaces the existing widget on screen. It just says "problem loading widget".

Any Idea??

Answer (score 8):

Did you change the class name of the broadcast receiver implementing your widget?  If so, don't do that.

Comment: Good call.  I also ended up having to change the name of the RemoteViewsService to match as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right behavior to me. As app is installed again, its widgets should be installed again too. If, for instance, there is a new activity to configure the widget, how do you know it as a user ?

There is, indeed, no way to guarantee that a new widget would run at all from this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course the related use-case where there was a widget loaded on the home page and the user then uninstalls the application that contains the widget and widget config app. I guess this is the same as a new version which must to an uninstall/install cycle.

When that happens, all you see is the "Problem Loading Widget" in a toast-like box on the home screen. As far as I can tell, the widget gets no indicatation that the package is being uninstalled and I guess then the home screen AppWidgetManager thows up a default message.

Not well thought out behaviour on the part of the OS team. I suggest that it would be better to call the widget's onDisbled() and onDestroy() methods and to remove the widgets from the home screen before the package is removed so they can tidy up if need be and the user (non-geek phone user) gets a clean experience.

All I can find is the indication that only the user can remove a widget from the home screen, says commonsguy: [Removing AppWidgets programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532121/removing-appwidgets-programmatically)

I sure us developers can handle the odd weird toast, but for non technical "ordinary" phone users this sort of behaviour drives them back to iPhones very quickly.