# Hiding android widget

Tags: android, widget

I have created a few home screen widgets for my Android application.  I would like to disable or enable some of these widgets from being added to the home screen based on some of the user's settings in my database.

Is it possible to dynamically disable/enable the user from adding certain widgets from my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532121/removing-appwidgets-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to dynamically disable/enable the user from adding certain widgets from my application?

If you disable/enable the `<receiver>` component via `PackageManager`, that should cause those app widgets to be unavailable from the menu... but it probably also screws up any outstanding instances of those app widgets.