# Android - Could I dispose Widget programmatically?

Tags: android, widget, dispose, destroy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing AppWidgets programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532121/removing-appwidgets-programmatically)

Question is like the Title:`Could widget be destroyed programmatically?` If yes, how can i do that. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "destroyed", you mean remove it from the home screen -- then no, I've never heard of anybody doing this.

For reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/5kqWygpdk4g

Comment: Yeah, thanks you! I think so but still ask to satisfy my boss :D