# Android remove widget on app uninstall

Tags: android, widget, uninstallation

I have a problem with a widget I have for an application.
If I put the widget on my homescreen, then I uninstall the application that my widget comes from, but the widget will not be removed on the homescreen. Instead of the widget there is a text saying: : "Loading".

Are there some kind of code I need to write so it gets removed when I uninstall the application on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the user has to manually remove widgets from the home screen. Here is a [reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/5kqWygpdk4g%5B1-25%5D)

Comment: Okey, I thought you could write some widget.destory or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should package your widget and your app in the **same APK**. Then, when you uninstall the app, the widget will automagically get removed.

**EDIT Unfortunately, I should have tested this before I posted. This does NOT work. You cannot programmatically remove the widget when the app is uninstalled. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532121/removing-appwidgets-programmatically) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Ooxc3jYd2FM%5B1-25%5D). 1000 Apologies for my incorrect advice :-(**

Comment: it won't. The code will, definitely, but your launcher may still hold 'zombie widget' unless you remove it manually.

Comment: So there is no way I can write some code to remove it when the application gets removed?

Comment: Oops. I was sure this worked, but I just tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work. So, no. You are in the same boat as all other app developers: When you app is uninsalled, your widget stays on the screen and says "problem loading..." (or whatever). Welcome to the club.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com You are sooo right and I am sooo wrong :-( I edited my answer and beg forgiveness.