# Remove Widget from home screen without drag and drop

Tags: android, android-widget, onclick, homescreen

I am working to make Launcher Application. I have created some temporary widgets for some purpose in my home screens. Now I want to remove that widgets from screen without drag and drop. So I want to know that it is possible or not ? And if possible then give some hint. I am also happy if i can remove widget on click of itself widget.

I have tried this but not working for me  `appWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(launcherAppWidgetInfo.appWidgetId);`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532121/removing-appwidgets-programmatically). It appears that this isn't possible: I guess to prevent changing a user's setup without explicit permission.

On the same page it shares why your current method does not work:

*Unfortunately, that does not work because deleteAppWidgetId() does not remove the widget from the home screen but just [stops listening to changes for this AppWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetHost.html#deleteAppWidgetId%28int%29)*

Comment: I just want to remove widget like NOVA Launcher. They can able to add widget and remove widget without drag and drop.

Comment: More evidence to the negative: _[App widgets (home screen widgets) live in separate process and you
have no control on adding/removing them. All you can do is tell in
your AndroidManifest.xml that you have a new appwidget and user will
seen it when he decides to place something to his homescreen._](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/5kqWygpdk4g.)

Not sure how NOVA managed it but so far all signs point to no.